# git merge - Files are still "dirty" after successful merge

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, merge, git-merge

After I did merge, solved the conflicts and comitted them, everything in the VS code is clean from merge conflicts.
But when I do yarn start and refresh couple of times, the console still shows me unexpected signs:

[image]

[image]

Even though the file is clean from that - I looked for those signs all over the computer, and no sign from them (I pretty much experienced with merging, though I'm not sure from where the browser get that files version - the one before the merging)

Deleting browser cache from all possible places, didn't help.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that, when you open `src/App.js` in your VS Code editor, line 157 doesn't have the `<<<<<<< HEAD` marker ? is the file saved ?

Comment: web app? Perhaps cache?

Comment: @LeGEC - exactly, the file is saved and still shoes this

Comment: @eftshift0 it's indeed a web app. It sounds to me like cache is the case, but I am not familiar with how to check whether it is cache isues, and if it is how to fix it.

Comment: did you commit your file after resolving the conflict?

Comment: @AmitBisht yap, commited and pushed... even aborted the merge several times and solved all again...

Comment: Are you sure you edited the file with removing the merge conflict markers and added the file to the staging area before committing the merge?

Comment: @dan1st yes. I even opened a pull request to check the file content, and it was exactly what I have in my VS - after successful merging and with the desired content after solving the conflicts.

Comment: One simple technique to check if it is cache is to make a request for the file with a different client.... say, `curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted node_modules/.cache and it helped:

https://dev.to/pnevares/webpack-isn-t-noticing-your-file-changes-did-you-do-something-wrong-34dc